# How to Compare results of Regression ML Model after each RUN programmatically

Tags: python, r

I wanted to write R code which will read and store Error Metrics like MAE,MAPE, R2 etc in a dataframe after each run and compare the results.

I am adding more training data in each run and want to crosscheck it how its improving/decreasing the error after I add data by using R code instead of manually checking each time.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic question, and the exact answer depends on the model you want to run. To help you at least to some extent, you need to understand that each fitted model that you run has a certain structure. For instance, consider the following:

```
# fix seed for reproducability
set.seed(42)

# generate fake data:
x = rnorm(100000)
y = x + 5*rnorm(100000)
df <- data.frame(y,x)
```

Have a look at the results returned from the summary method of a linear model (please also explore `names(lm(y~x, data = df)))`):

```
names(summary(lm(y~x, data = df)))
 [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients"  "aliased"       "sigma"         "df"            "r.squared"    
 [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled"
```

You see that the R^2 and the adjusted R^2 are returned. If you were interested in this quantity, you could fit your model multiple times, extract this quantity, and store it in whatever way you want. Tayloring this to your example, let's say we want to extract the R^2 for each run on data up to a given index, we could define the following function:

```
get_rsq <- function(ind){
  summary(lm(y~x, data = df[1:ind,]))$r.squared
}
```

and run

```
sapply(seq(1000, nrow(df), 10000), get_rsq)
 [1] 0.05720826 0.04352535 0.03907049 0.03851629 0.04007696 0.04063812 0.04058338 0.03924757 0.03934495 0.03926088
```

to get the R^2s for each fit where we use `seq(1000, nrow(df), 10000)` to increment the index in the dataframe and thus the amount of data we use to fit the model (by 10000 in each iteration). Please make sure the data is shuffled.

Note that in the same way that I have defined `get_rsq`, you can define your own functions to extract whatever quantity you want from your fitted models.

There are many existing packages that help with this kind of exercise. For instance, have a look at the [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) package, or read some [blog posts](https://www.r-bloggers.com/learning-from-learning-curves/). Depending on your application, the [broom-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) with it's function `tidy` and `glance` might be helpful as well. For instance, the following gives you all summary statistics collected by glance in a dataframe, with one row for each incremental data partition:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

bind_rows(lapply(seq(1000, nrow(df), 10000), function(x) glance(lm(y~x, data = df[1:x,]))  ))
    r.squared adj.r.squared     sigma  statistic       p.value df      logLik       AIC        BIC   deviance df.residual
1  0.05720826    0.05626358 0.9896907   60.55827  1.778778e-14  2   -1407.575   2821.15   2835.873   977.5288         998
2  0.04352535    0.04343838 0.9734098  500.47514 1.924959e-108  2  -15310.872  30627.74  30649.662 10420.8975       10998
3  0.03907049    0.03902473 0.9768702  853.75895 5.281910e-184  2  -29305.279  58616.56  58640.414 20037.8762       20998
4  0.03851629    0.03848528 0.9805112 1241.75589 9.551206e-267  2  -43375.978  86757.96  86782.980 29801.5469       30998
5  0.04007696    0.04005355 0.9802690 1711.67402  0.000000e+00  2  -57358.419 114722.84 114748.703 39396.0941       40998
6  0.04063812    0.04061931 0.9793373 2160.25156  0.000000e+00  2  -71300.030 142606.06 142632.579 48912.2650       50998
7  0.04058338    0.04056766 0.9785619 2580.21927  0.000000e+00  2  -85232.308 170470.62 170497.672 58410.6772       60998
8  0.03924757    0.03923404 0.9778149 2900.32974  0.000000e+00  2  -99150.760 198307.52 198335.030 67882.7501       70998
9  0.03934495    0.03933309 0.9789331 3317.38429  0.000000e+00  2 -113208.374 226422.75 226450.655 77621.2003       80998
10 0.03926088    0.03925032 0.9789433 3718.65928  0.000000e+00  2 -127185.787 254377.57 254405.830 87206.1159       90998
```

Comment: Thanks @coffeinjunky, its very helpful.one more question, how to handle the same when I am passing new data to the already trained model after every 15 days and so on rather than using something like this " seq(1000,nrow(df),10000)" as you mentioned. Can that be done?

Comment: Well, in that case you would just append the rows to the dataframe and re-estimate, wouldn't you? Have a look at `dplyr::bind_rows` or `rbind`. Depending on the size of your data, it might be an idea to set it up using a gradient descent approach, and to use the new data as a new batch for a gradient step. Check out Andrew Ng's machine learning curse for a more in-depth discussion of real-time model fitting. Having said that, since you are using R and talk about 15 days in between, this is probably not the required way to go.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot.,